# Changing files privacy settings

Tags: files

One of the content types I have defined has a file-field set up with a destination to public folder.

The field is supposed to have private settings, but as some data has been saved on the server I can not change it any more.

How can I fix it without deleting all the content of the server?

Comment: You cannot apply any restrictions to public files because Drupal will not involve in the file request.

Comment: I know there is no easy solution. For now my best idea is to remove the files field, add a new one with proper settings and upload all the files again. Unfortunately this will mean whole day of very boring work. I was hoping there is a way I can do it faster. Maybe exporting - importing the data, or copying them to private folder and then patching the database with queries.

Comment: File field only stores the file ID, and the actual location of the file should be in the `files` table. See if you can run some sort of script to update all of them to `private://` path (from current `public://e.jog` format).

Comment: Ayesh, I've found the links in the file_managed table and they should be easily fixable. The only problem left is to force-change the field settings to private.